# Problem with keepalived startup

Tags: raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, pi-hole

I run pihole across two Raspberry PIs, an older PI 3B+ (server B) and a 4 (server A). Both are running Bullseye.

Simply because the 4 is new and a little more powerful, it is used as the primary server for pihole.

I have noticed something a little odd - if I reboot server A, keepalived fails over correctly to B, and pihole carries on from the server B - however, when server A comes back online, keepalived does not fail back. So this probably isn't a pihole issue, but something more fundamental in the way the failover is configured.

If I issue systemctl service restart keepalived on server A, it fails back to server A correctly. I cannot see anything obviously wrong - the PI boots okay, and I can access it remotely without any problems. So my suspicion is that somehow keepalived was trying to do something before the network services were started up fully, so I added a crude sleep 30 into the keepalived init script. However, that has not resolve this.

I have gone through the keepalived.conf repeatedly, and as far as I can tell, the fault probably isn't there. However, this is the configuration from server A

```
global_defs {
router_id pihole-dns-01
script_user root
enable_script_security
}

vrrp_script chk_ftl {
script "/etc/scripts/chk_ftl"
interval 5 # run interval`
weight -10
fall 2 # no. of fails required for failover
rise 2 # no. of successes required for failback
timeout 4
}

vrrp_instance PIHOLE {
state MASTER
interface eth0
virtual_router_id 55
priority 150
advert_int 1
unicast_src_ip 192.168.1.62
unicast_peer {
192.168.1.60
}
debug 1

authentication {
auth_type PASS
auth_pass xxxxxxxx
}

virtual_ipaddress {
192.168.1.61/24
}

track_script {
chk_ftl
}

}
```

and server B

```
global_defs {
router_id pihole-dns-02
script_user root
enable_script_security
}

vrrp_script chk_ftl {
script "/etc/scripts/chk_ftl"
interval 5 # run interval
#weight -10
fall 2 # no. of fails required for failover
rise 2 # no. of successes required for failback
timeout 4
}

vrrp_instance PIHOLE {
state BACKUP
interface eth0
virtual_router_id 55
priority 145
advert_int 1
unicast_src_ip 192.168.1.60
unicast_peer {
192.168.1.62
}

authentication {
auth_type PASS
auth_pass xxxxxxxxxx
}

virtual_ipaddress {
192.168.1.61/24
}

track_script {
chk_ftl
}

}
```

The only clue I have seen is in the messages file after a reboot on server A

It looks like some sort of problem with unicast binding, but I don't understand why a service restart would fix that.
This is the systemctl service status

```
since Sun 2023-06-11 18:41:38 BST; 2min 51s ago
   Main PID: 638 (keepalived)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 3948)
        CPU: 2.810s
     CGroup: /system.slice/keepalived.service
             ├─638 /usr/sbin/keepalived --dont-fork
             └─743 /usr/sbin/keepalived --dont-fork

Jun 11 18:41:40 deckard Keepalived[638]: Starting VRRP child process, pid=743
Jun 11 18:41:40 deckard Keepalived_vrrp[743]: Registering Kernel netlink reflec>
Jun 11 18:41:40 deckard Keepalived_vrrp[743]: Registering Kernel netlink comman>
Jun 11 18:41:40 deckard Keepalived_vrrp[743]: Opening file '/etc/keepalived/kee>
Jun 11 18:41:40 deckard Keepalived_vrrp[743]: (PIHOLE): entering FAULT state (i>
Jun 11 18:41:40 deckard Keepalived_vrrp[743]: (PIHOLE) entering FAULT state
Jun 11 18:41:40 deckard Keepalived_vrrp[743]: Registering gratuitous ARP shared>
Jun 11 18:41:40 deckard Keepalived_vrrp[743]: bind unicast_src 192.168.1.62 fai>
Jun 11 18:41:40 deckard Keepalived_vrrp[743]: VRRP_Script(chk_ftl) succeeded
Jun 11 18:41:42 deckard Keepalived_vrrp[743]: Netlink reports eth0 up
```

and this is from the messages file at the same time

```
Jun 11 18:41:40 deckard Keepalived_vrrp[743]: (PIHOLE): entering FAULT state (interface eth0 down)
Jun 11 18:41:40 deckard Keepalived_vrrp[743]: (PIHOLE) entering FAULT state
Jun 11 18:41:40 deckard Keepalived_vrrp[743]: Registering gratuitous ARP shared channel
Jun 11 18:41:40 deckard Keepalived_vrrp[743]: bind unicast_src 192.168.1.62 failed 99 - Cannot assign requested address
```

Any idea or suggestions?